# Is there any way to extract year and month from date data in R by tidyverse or anything?

Tags: r, zoo, tidyverse

If the `data.frame` contains `20100101`, `2010-01-01`, `2010/01/01`, three types style time data, how can I get the column like "%Y-%m" or `Jan 2010`.

---

Thank @akrun, it works for me.

````
# `XXXX-XX`
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(
  x = "20100101"
) 
df %>%
  mutate(yearMon = format(lubridate::ymd(x), "%Y-%m"))
```

# `Jan XXXX`
```{r}
df %>%
mutate(yearMon = zoo::as.yearmon(lubridate::ymd(x)))
```
````

Comment: If you just have different types of delimiters, then strip them out and format - `format(as.Date(gsub("[^0-9]","",x), format="%Y%m%d"), "%b %Y")`

Answer (score 4):

As they all follow year, month, day, we can use `ymd`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     mutate(yearMon = format(ymd(Date), "%Y-%m"))
     #if we need format "Jan 2010"
     #mutate(yearMon = format(ymd(Date), "%b-%Y"))
```

Another option is `yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
    mutate(yearMon = as.yearmon(ymd(Date)))
```

Comment: The yearmon solution could be: `as.yearmon(gsub("\\D", "", Date), "%Y%m%d")` in which case lubridate is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime` library as there is no one consistent format of dates.

```
library(anytime)
format(anytime(x), format = "%b %Y")

#[1] "Jan 10" "Jan 10" "Jan 10"
```

OR

```
format(anytime(x), format = "%Y-%m")

#[1] "2010-01" "2010-01" "2010-01"
```

**data**

```
x <- c('20100101', '2010-01-01', '2010/01/01')
```